# Angular: load environment properties before config/run

Tags: angularjs, environment-variables, angular-promise, angular-http, angular-providers

I'm developing a angular app, and this app has about a 10 configurable properties (depending on the environment and client).

I had those properties in json config files, but this is really troublesome: there must be specific builds per env/company. So I would like to retrieve those properties once from the backend on app load.

So in order to do this I created a Provider

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [...]);
app.provider('environment', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.environment;

    self.loadEnvironment = function (configuration, $http, $q) {
        var def = $q.defer();
        $http(...)
        .success(function (data) {
            self.environment = Environment.build(...);
            def.resolve(self.environment);
        }).error(function (err) {
            ...
        });
        return def.promise;
    };

    self.$get = function(configuration, $http, $q) {
        if (!_.isUndefined(self.environment)) {
            return $q.resolve(self.environment);
        }
        return self.loadEnvironment(configuration, $http, $q);
    };
}
app.config(... 'environmentProvider', function(... environment) {
    ...
    //The problem here is that I can't do environment.then(...) or something similar... 
    //Environment does exists though, with the available functions... 
}
```

How to properly work with this Provider that executes a rest call to populate his environment variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What a wonderful scenario mate :D! But seriously though, would you mind if the environment were a `constant` or a `value`? I think is a better aproach.

Comment: @thomas are you using any build tools like gulp?

Comment: Using grunt, (and for some builds even maven above it)... The app has a huge scope, and we're using constants atm, but this is not good enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excelent scenario to explore angularjs features.

Assuming that you really need the environment data loaded before the app loads, you can use angular tools to load the environment and then declare a `value` or a `constant` to store your environment configs before the app bootstraps.

So, instead of using `ng-app` to start your app, you must use [`angular.bootstrap`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) to bootstrap it manually.

> **Observations:** You mustn't use `ng-app` once you are bootstrapping the app manually, otherwise your app will load with the angular default system without respecting your environment loading. Also, make sure to bootstrap your application after declare all module components; i.e. declare all controllers, servieces, directives, etc. so then, you call `angular.bootstrap`

The below code implements the solution described previously:

```
(function() {
    var App = angular.module("myApp", []);

    // it will return a promisse of the $http request
    function loadEnvironment () {
        // loading angular injector to retrieve the $http service
        var ngInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
        var $http = ngInjector.get("$http");

        return $http.get("/environment-x.json").then(function(response) {
            // it could be a value as well
            App.constant("environment ", response.data);
        }, function(err) {
            console.error("Error loading the application environment.", err)
        });
    }

    // manually bootstrap the angularjs app in the root document
    function bootstrapApplication() {
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);
        });
    }

    // load the environment and declare it to the app
    // so then bootstraps the app starting the application
    loadEnvironment().then(bootstrapApplication);
}());
```

Comment: Promising answer! I was implementing the same, but without an angular context before (so just $.get(...) and then bootstrapping), let me try!

Comment: How would you combine the `app.config([...])` and `app.run(...)` with that? I currently get unknown provider errors (atm for $q)

Comment: So what I do is 
`var app = angular.module('myApp', [... lot of providers...]);
app.config([...some providers and environment..., function(...) { ... });
app.run(...);
function loadEnvironment() { ... returns promise... }
function bootstrapApplication() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
}
loadEnvironment().then(bootstrapApplication, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});`

Comment: You can segregate this in a proper order, just make sure to declare every thing before bootstrap your app. For example, you can declare your module separatedly, and then, you just use a getter to retrieve the module like so : `var app = angular.module('myApp'); `.

Comment: Also this solution doesn't use `$q` directly your error must be something else, and I tested on both `.config` and `.run` being injected with the `environment` constant and it worked normally.