# How to change Angular factory to resolve before injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-factory

I have an existing application that uses a `MapProvider` like so:

```
mapModule.factory('MapProvider', ['$injector', function($injector) {
    return $injector.get('GoogleMapsService');        
}]);
```

This MapProvider is used extensively across the application and is injected into various other controllers and services (rightly or wrongly).

I now need to add a `BaiduMapsService`, which I have been able to get working as a test with:

```
mapModule.factory('MapProvider', ['$injector', function($injector) {
    if(true) {
        return $injector.get('GoogleMapsService');
    } else {
        return $injector.get('BaiduMapsService');
    }
}]);
```

And flipping the `if` value accordingly. (Both of these services are using a TypeScript interface, so have the same methods). Now, I need to add a `$http` call to the API, which will return which map to use, based on the provided data. How can I make my factory asynchronous, *without* having to change all my `MapProvider.someCallHere()` calls to `MapProvider.then(m => m.someCallHere())`.

Ideally, when `MapProvider` is injected across my application, it will be able to resolve using the async data (only once), and then inject the necessary service afterwards.

Alternatively, is there a way to defer / delay loading Angular at all, until I make an API call and set some global data somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can postpone the application `bootstrap` (also, don't use `ng-app`, do it manually) until you get data from server. I've answered this before on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107496/angular-load-environment-properties-before-config-run/40109316#40109316) but each case has its own specific details.

I usually see a config value being declared on the app before the application gets bootstraped, this is very useful for multi-tenant apps. So that this preference values can be used in the whole app as an injected provider.

For example:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

// retrieve the $http provider
var ngInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
var $http = ngInjector.get("$http");

// load config function. Returns a promise.
function loadConfig(){
    return $http.get("/config.json").then(function(response) {
        // declare the configuration value on your app
        app.constant("Config", response.data);
    }, function(err) {
        console.error("Error loading the application config.", err)
    });
}

// Call loadConfig then bootstrap the app
loadConfig().then(function () {
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });
});
```

Finally from your factory, you can use the `Config` constant to retrieve the preferred map.

```
mapModule.factory('MapProvider', ['$injector', 'Config', function($injector, Config) {
    if(Config.preferedMap == 'GoogleMap') {
        return $injector.get('GoogleMapsService');
    } else {
        return $injector.get('BaiduMapsService');
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think is to hold initialize whole `angular` (and modules) until you got your "config" (and set is as global variable).