# How to lazy load configurations before angular boostrap?

Tags: angular

In order to configure our service dynamically we have a server which serves a configuration file. We load this in a `loadEnvironment` function (XMLHttpRequest which resolves when environment has been set) with a reference to the existing environment like this:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { loadEnvironment } from './environments/load-environment';

loadEnvironment(environment).then(() => {
  if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
  }
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

and then we start boostrapping the module. I wanted this to happen synchronously, that we await the config, `then(...` initiate the app.

AppModule looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    IamModule.forRoot(IamModule.constructConfigFromEnvironment(environment, "exposed"))
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

But through logging (and using breakpoints), the module (`IamModule` in this case) initializes before the `loadEnvironment`, somehow. Is there some hidden optimization going on? How can I ensure that it loads after the config has been loaded?

I noticed that my question is similar to this: [Angular: load environment properties before config/run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107496/angular-load-environment-properties-before-config-run), but that I'm already using the answer suggested there (in different syntax) so I don't understand why it's not working.

Using angular 12

---

**Update**: I did a bit more digging and I suspect the angular AOT compiler is doing some black magic. The app seems to detect that it's being bootstrapped in some file where AppModule is imported, and then takes some shortcuts before the bootstrapping should begin.

Bootstrapping AppModule like this "works" (in the sense that it loads after the environment loader promise has been resolved):

```
loadEnvironment(environment).then(() => {
  if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
  }
  import("./app/app.module").then((AppModule: any) => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  })
});
```

but it seems to cause a heap of new issues.

Comment: Your setup looks okay. It sounds strange indeed that your module is already doing something, unless (1) - your module has some self-starting code (it’s already loaded after all as it is inside one big js file after compilation) or (2) - your loadEnviroment resolves too early maybe..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can you APP_INITIALIZER token of angular and can read about it here :- https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: I think using this design is more akin to angular, will rewrite. Thank you